# Using replace javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a simple function to replace some strings.

**Rules:**

- Every `dot` must be replaced by **"_attributes."**;
- Every `[numbers]` must be replaced by `.numbers`; (`numbers` means 1, 123... and so on)

Actually I wrote the replace like this:

```
str.replace(/(\[?\d*\]?\.)/g, '_attributes$1')
   .replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, '.$1');
```

**Input examples:**

```
model.city
model[0].city
model0.city
model[0].another_model[4].city
```

**Expected output:**

```
model_attributes.city
model_attributes.0.city
model0_attributes.city
model_attributes.0.another_model_attributes.4.city
```

It's almost done, except that it fails for the case that I have a number (without brackets) before a `dot` like this:

```
model0.city
```

It prints:

```
model_attributes0.city
```

While I expect it to be:

```
model0_attributes.city
```

Below is a simple snippet that you play and see what I'm trying to achieve:

```js
var fields = [
  'model.city', 
  'model[0].city', 
  'model0.city', 
  'model[0].another_model[4].city',
  'model[0].another_model4.city'
];

var expectedArr = [
  'model_attributes.city',
  'model_attributes.0.city',
  'model0_attributes.city',
  'model_attributes.0.another_model_attributes.4.city',
  'model_attributes.0.another_model4_attributes.city'
];

var replacedArr = [];
for (const field of fields) {
  var replaced = field.replace(/(\[?\d*\]?\.)/g, '_attributes$1').replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, '.$1');
  replacedArr.push(replaced);
}

console.log('expected => ', expectedArr);
console.log('actual => ', replacedArr);
```

What I have to change in my replace `function` to make it work? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first regex, just make a cluster group optional, like this

`str.replace(/((?:\[\d+\])?\.)/g, '_attributes$1')`

and you're good to go.

Expanded

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?: \[ \d+ \] )?              # Optional '[ddd]' group
      \.                            # Required dot
 )                             # (1 end)
```

JS sample

```js
function PrintMod( str )
{
    console.log( str.replace(/((?:\[\d+\])?\.)/g, '_attributes$1')
       .replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, '.$1') );
}

PrintMod( 'model.city' );
PrintMod( 'model[0].city' );
PrintMod( 'model0.city' );
PrintMod( 'model[0].another_model[4].city' );
PrintMod( 'model[0].another_model4.city' );
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you're looking for:

```js
var fields = [
  'model.city', 
  'model[0].city', 
  'model0.city', 
  'model[0].another_model[4].city',
  'model[0].another_model4.city'
];

var expectedArr = [
  'model_attributes.city',
  'model_attributes.0.city',
  'model0_attributes.city',
  'model_attributes.0.another_model_attributes.4.city',
  'model_attributes.0.another_model4_attributes.city'
];

var replacedArr = [];
for (const field of fields) {
  var replaced = field.replace(/(\[\d+\])?\./g, '_attributes$1.').replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, '.$1');
  replacedArr.push(replaced);
}

console.log('expected => ', expectedArr);
console.log('actual => ', replacedArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```